# 'Frame' does not contain a definition for 'CornerRadius' (Frame)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Visual Studio shows the error in the title for a **Xamarin.Forms** `Frame`. The [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Frame.CornerRadius/) on the other hand do contain `CornerRadius`. Is there something needed to be done to enable it?

Comment: Relative to the `c#` tag, I see a [`System.Windows.Controls.Frame`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Maybe try using the fully qualified name, or tell us the output of `typeof(Frame).FullName`. Maybe you have an old version or something.

Comment: @Quantic Thanks. But that's why I included a link to the docs - I'm referring to Xamarin Forms Frame. I now edited my question to be clearer.

Comment: Hm in hindsight it is not a helpful comment especially considering your rep, and VS would give "Error CS0104" if there was an ambiguous reference or something. It looks like that property was added recently on [November 22, 2016](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/releases): "[Enhancement] Added CornerRadius property To Frame control", so it could still be from an old version.

Comment: @Quantic `in hindsight it is not a helpful comment especially considering your rep` - thanks, but I fear the relationship between rep and knowledge might be quite overestimated here :) And your second point is probably the answer - you can make an answer out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That property was added recently on [November 22, 2016](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/releases) for the 2.3.4-pre1 update: "[Enhancement] Added CornerRadius property To Frame control". The fix is likely to update to that version or later.